# Object of Class could not be converted to string CI Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting an error in the bellow code and I am unable to find out what is the reason for it. I am glad if you can help me with this.

```
Public function () {
$query =  $this->db->select_sum("cost_after_discount");
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_payment');
$data  = $query;
return $data;
}
```

> Object of Class could not be converted to string CI Error

Comment: Can you `print_r($data)`?

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Comment: are you trying to echo $data ;

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code. First you have to provide a name for your function then you do not use any result method to return result. So try following

```
Public function xyz() {
 $this->db->select_sum("cost_after_discount");
 $query = $this->db->get('tbl_payment');
 $data  = $query->result_array();
 return $data;
}
```

now you may call this `xyz` function to retrieve data

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function retrive() 
{
  $this->db->select_sum("cost_after_discount");
  $query = $this->db->get('tbl_payment');
  $data  = $query->result_array();
  var_dump($data);
 }
```

This should do :)